# Cant store data in setState react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First I check if Localstorage is supported, if it is I check if there is an item query in localstorage. If there is a item it should update to the query state. Before setState I have an alert and it alerts the item fine. But after the setState I alert again but it displays nothing? Somebody knows why? Even if I replace `this.setState({query: localStorage.getItem("query")})` with `this.setState({query: 'test'})` it doesnt display test in the alert?

```
getLocalStorage = () => {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

        if (localStorage.getItem("query") !== null) {
            //Alerts 'a string'
            alert(localStorage.getItem("query"));

            this.setState({
                query: localStorage.getItem("query")
            });

            //Alerts nothing?
            alert(this.state.query);
            this.search();
        }
        else{
            this.getLocation();
        }
    }
    else {
        this.getLocation();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**setState won't show direct change it will take time :**

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

**If you want state value just after it's set you have to use it like this :**

```
this.setState({
    query: localStorage.getItem("query")
},() => {
    alert(this.state.query);
});
```

For more details , please read [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: @JustinTime, My Pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

setState is asynchronous method so that way you are geting this kind of response. So for this bug you can see -

[Is there a synchronous alternative of setState() in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018342/is-there-a-synchronous-alternative-of-setstate-in-reactjs)