# How to batch React setState() calls together inside an async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, race-condition, setstate

So I have run into an issue where React is not batching together multiple setState() calls inside of an async function (React usually does this automatically outside of an async function). This means that when my code is run, multiple consecutive setState() calls conflict with eachother, the first setState() causes the component to update and the second setState() happens before the component has had enough time to remount and I get the error "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component". I did some research and found out that this is expected behaviour but I've found nothing about how to fix the issue.

Here's some example code (doesn't run) just to visualise what I'm trying to say. In this case the lines
setData(response.data);
and
setLoading(false);
conflict and cause the error.

I need some way to make the two calls atomic.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const Demo = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await callAPI();
    if (response.status === 200) {
      setData(response.data);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button disabled={loading} onClick={() => fetchData()}>
        Fetch Data
      </Button>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

Comment: you may find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018342/is-there-a-synchronous-alternative-of-setstate-in-reactjs

Comment: you need to use useEffect hook for this.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-bas-bklnl

Comment: @ChrisG I'm sure his example would work fine, it doesn't unmount/mount any components upon state updating. I'm left wondering what the OP's actual code looks like and why it is remounting components so frequently instead of just updating state/props and simply rerendering.

Comment: I can easily replicate the error by unmounting the component while its xhr is running. Upon finishing, the code tries to change the state of an unmounted component, which causes the error. So the fix isn't to batch stuff together, it's to keep the component mounted while the xhr is running.

Comment: Thanks for all the attention this is getting, @ChrisG I am getting the same error with your code sand box.

Comment: Yeah, I modified it to replicate the error.

Comment: @ChrisG, I see. I played around a bit more and it seems you're absolutely right. This actually does work. I think mine is failing because the "loading" state is actually coming from a context that is being consumed in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can avoid that making loading as a standalone boolean variable instead of part of component's state. Another approach would be to use `useEffect` to delay API call until your `loading` variable change. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914175/8873517) has got your covered. And lastly, you can make use of class components - `setState()` function accepts a callback as a second param - that was the way of making atomic state changes before hooks came into place.

Comment: Actually it was best practice to use componentDidUpdate not the second param callback. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Yes, use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function instead of going down the road of "nested hell" with using the `setState` callback parameter to issue further state updates.

Answer (score 0):

You could batch your states together into one composite state object and do it something like this...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const Demo = () => {
  const [demoState, setDemoState] = useState({data: null, loading: false});

  const fetchData = () => {
    setDemoState({...demoState, loading: true});
    callAPI()
      .then( response => handleResponse(response)} );
  }

  const handleResponse = (response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      setDemoState({data: response.data, loading: false});
    } else {
      setDemoState({...demoState, loading: false});
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button disabled={loading} onClick={() => fetchData()}>
        Fetch Data
      </Button>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(demoState.data)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine loading and data to the one state.
and also instead of loading use status.

for eg:

```
/** status possible values can be: "idle", "pending", "resolved", "rejected"*/

const [state, setState] = useState({status: "idle", data: null})
```

now you can easily change the status and base on that handle different things