# State value doesn't change when I call a function with setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
addTOList= (id) =>{
  const movieId = id
  const movie = movies.find( ({ id }) => id === movieId );
  const stateMovie = [...this.state.movie, movie]
  console.log(stateMovie)
  this.setState({
    movie : stateMovie
  })
  console.log(this.state.movie)
  localStorage.setItem('movies', JSON.stringify(this.state.movie))
  this.state.movie.map(mov =>{
  })
}
```

This function will be triggered when the (Add to list) button is clicked.
but I have to click twice to change the state.`
sorry for horrible English

Comment: State only changes during re-render, so the value will never change during the function.

Answer (score 0):

react state changes are synchronous.

Check this question & answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018342/is-there-a-synchronous-alternative-of-setstate-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

If your 'next state' depends on the 'previous state' then you should use this pattern:

```
  this.setState(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    movie : [...prev.movie, movie],
  }))
```

Also you must wait until the state change has been applied by react before you will see the changes in your console statement.

Answer (score 0):

setState is an async function, it do not setstate in async manner but later, you can use a callback function, if you want to run a code snippet after set state is run:

`addTOList = () => {
    this.setState({
         movie : stateMovie
    }, () => {
     console.log(this.state.movie)
    })
}`