# React Native useState not setting state

Tags: javascript, react-native, state, use-state

I have this code below:

```
const [clientID, setClientID] = useState({});

// explodeClientID is an object
let explodeClientID = ClientIDFormatter(routeParams.QRData);
// I assign that variable to me clientID state:
setClientID(explodeClientID);

// I logged the variable:
console.log("Exploded Client ID:")
console.log(explodeClientID);
/* OUTPUT: 
Exploded Client ID:
Object {
  "BR_ID": 1,        
  "ClientChkID": 4,  
  "ClientID": 599920,
} */

// I logged the state:
console.log("Client ID: ");
console.log(clientID);
/* OUTPUT 
Client ID:
Object {}
*/
```

As you can see, the main problem is that when I assign `explodeClientID` to a regular variable, it has value. But when I use `setState` to update, it still returns an empty object. This shouldn't be an issue at all since it's not an API call that I need to await.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a synchronous alternative of setState() in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018342/is-there-a-synchronous-alternative-of-setstate-in-reactjs)

Comment: @JaredSmith the post you linked changes value on a click, I want to change the value on component load. I also used useEffect for this but the value is still null.

Comment: The problem is the same and the answer is the same. There's no synchronous version of `setState`, not in classes, not in hooks. It makes no sense: if you already have the value, then pass that as the initial value to `useState`, don't trigger a pointless re-render on mount. Why are you passing an empty object instead of explodeClientID?

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this:

```
const [clientID, setClientID] = useState({});

// explodeClientID is an object
let explodeClientID = ClientIDFormatter(routeParams.QRData);
// I assign that variable to me clientID state:
setClientID(explodeClientID);

// I logged the variable:
console.log("Exploded Client ID:")
console.log(explodeClientID);
/* OUTPUT: 
Exploded Client ID:
Object {
  "BR_ID": 1,        
  "ClientChkID": 4,  
  "ClientID": 599920,
} */

React.useEfect(()=>{
console.log(clientID)
}, [clientID])
```